# Calculated Field: How to display 'Approval Status'

Tags: sharepoint

In a calculated field in SharePoint, how do I display the approval status?

I've tried =TEXT([Approval Status]) but it doesn't work.

Any Ideas? thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?  If we can understand your requirements better we can probably help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the connection between approval status and calculated field. To be able to approve or denier a list item you can activate the moderation option. You can do this in the menu "List settings" >> "Versioning settings" >> "Content Approval".

If you turn it on, the moderation column should be automatically added to you standard list view and displayed there.

To change the moderation status of a list item through code, you can simply set the Status property of the ModerationInformation property of the list item. It can be set to Approved, Denied, Scheduled, Draft or Pending.

```
listItem.ModerationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Approved;
```